# Except block not recovering from error

Tags: python, try-catch

In the following code for my RPG, I deal with user input and therefore create my code in a way that it can handle errors. When the user enters in a game command such as `acquire` (which takes two arguments) shown below, the acquire function is called, which tries to use the second part of the split input. If the user only enters 'acquire' and there is no second part to the split string, I expect that the IndexError raises and some text is printed. Again, when my code then tries to access `RawInput[1]` through the `Items` dictionary and fails to find it, I expect the KeyError to be raised and the text printed. None of this is happening for me.

When each of these errors should be raising, the error that I'm expecting to occur occurs, but the try/ except block does recover from it.

```
Items = {
'Rapier': Item('Rapier', 1, [None, None], 2)}

def Acquire(self):
    try:
        if Pos[0] == self.Pos[0] and Pos[1] == self.Pos[1]:
            for i in range(1, 4):
                j = i - 1
                if self.Type == i and not Inventory[j]:
                    Inventory[j] = self
                    self.Pos = None
                    print(Name, 'picked up the', self.Name)
                elif None not in Inventory:
                    print(Name, 'cannot carry any more!')
        else:
            print('There is no', RawInput[1].title(), 'here')
    except KeyError:
        print('That doesn\'t exist!')
    except IndexError:
        print('Acquire takes two arguments')

def ParseInput():
    global RawInput
    RawInput = input('> ').lower().split(' ', 1)

    if RawInput[0] == 'acquire':
        Acquire(Items[RawInput[1].title().strip()])
```

Could anyone explain to me how to fix my code or explain what is happening?

Comment: What *is* happening when an error should be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you're trying to catch won't occur inside of the code itself, but rather when the code is interpreted. putting the try-except around the function call should fix it.

```
if RawInput[0] == 'acquire':
    try:
        Acquire(Items[RawInput[1].title().strip()])
    except KeyError:
        print('That doesn\'t exist!')
    except IndexError:
        print('Acquire takes two arguments')
```